# Why is SSIS converting UTC datetime from XML source to SQL Server local time during import?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

While importing an XML file into a SQL Server tables, I find that all of my datetime fields which are in UTC have been converted to the SQL Server local time.

I don't want this default behaviour and would like to keep all UTC time as the way they appear in the XML files.

This is an example of two datetime fields in XML and then after they are imported into SQL Server:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what are the data types of the `DEP_DATE` and `RET_DATE` columns? How exactly are you getting the data from XML to SQL Server via SSIS? The SQL Server `datetime` and `datetime2` data types have no knowledge of UTC offsets, you need `datetimeoffset` for that, so it would seem that the client process doing the import could be "helping" by translating time zones.